# Using results of query multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

How do I use the result of a query multiple times

```
$query=...;
$resultsaved=mysql_query($query, $db);
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
    $result=$resultsaved;
     while($rowarray = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)){
        //do stuff depending on $i and $rowarray
     }
}
```

However after its first iteration, $resultsaved is destroyed; is there a more efficient way than $result=mysql_query($query, $db); a hundred times

Comment: `$resultsaved` isn't destroyed in the code you're showing us? Why can't you use it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a temporary variable. As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) about `mysql_fetch_array` says:

> Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the
>   internal data pointer ahead.

So, after the while loop you need to reset the internal pointer with `mysql_data_seek`:

```
$query=...;
$result=mysql_query($query, $db);
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
     while($rowarray = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)){
        //do stuff depending on $i and $rowarray
     }
     mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
}
```